# fix a div to the bottom of the 100% container and allow the while container to scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, fixed

I've got a 100% height container, I want to align a button 10% from the bottom and still allow the button to scroll.

Here's a fiddle of what i have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/e7cc9qq7/8/

Here's the css for the button

```
#button {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  bottom:10%;
  position:fixed;
  background:red;
}
```

Comment: Every thing works great whats your problem

Comment: The button's doesn't scroll, I want to align the button to the bottom of the container and still allow the button to scroll

Comment: Should make your button `absolute` instead of `fixed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `position: absolute` on the button, not `position: fixed`. And make sure the parent container has `position: relative`

```
#test1 {
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
    background:pink;
    position: relative;
}
#button {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    bottom:10%;
    position: absolute;
    background:red;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jth2013/e7cc9qq7/9/)**

Comment: Thanks, I tried that first but perhaps I didn't spell it correct or something, thought I was going mad, works ok now. Thanks